# How do you view the full Location path in the References dialog in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

i am working on a visual basic 6 project. when i go to the References dialog for the project, the Location path for one of the references is cut off so that i can't see the end of the path. does anyone know of a way to find out what the full path is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways. Unfortunately, both require you to select (place checkmark in box) the item(s) of interest in the References dialog, whether you want them or not.

First way is to open the Object Browser window, then select one of the libraries of interest from the top-left selector (which usually defaults to ). When you do that, the details pane at the very bottom of the Object Browser window should show you the full path to the DLL. (As a bonus, it will be selectable for Copy/Paste too!)

Second way is to open the *.vbp (Visual Basic Project) file with Notepad (or other text editor), and look for the Reference= entries. For components used on Forms, you can also open *.frm files, and again look for Reference= entries.

Comment: i'll give you credit for a useful answer as well. thanks for the extra bit about the object browser window.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have VB6 installed these days to check how to do it in-editor, but you can always just view the VBP file with a text editor.  The same paths that would be shown in the dialog window are listed there.

Comment: you're right, i open the .vbp file in notepad and voila! i see all the reference paths. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly simple (for a programmer) method to just make the VB6 references dialog larger:

> ### [Redesign IDE Dialogs](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/03/02/redesign-ide-dialogs.aspx)
>
> By Karl E. Peterson 03/02/2010
>
> ...there's a tool you can use to do modify these sorts of settings to
>   your heart's content. Resource Hacker is a freeware utility to view,
>   modify, rename, add, delete and extract resources in 32-bit Windows
>   executables and resource files. I've long found it one of the best
>   tools available to explore "the guts" (resources) of executables.
>
> ResHacker offers a dialog tool that's extremely similar to Classic
>   VB's -- you just drag the dialog elements around, resizing them to
>   suit. Or you can edit the raw resource script, and watch the changes
>   play out in the dialog designer. Simply open the "Dialog" node in the
>   treeview, find the dialog you want to edit, and go to town. When
>   you're happy with the new design, press the "Compile Script" button,
>   then just do a File | Save to write the changes to disk. (Be sure to
>   make a backup of the original file, first, of course, unless you enjoy
>   doing re-installs.)
>
> To modify the Classic VB Project-References dialog, open the
>   VB6IDE.DLL (or VB5IDE.DLL) file in ResHacker, find Dialog #4040 and
>   get to work. ...

Here's there result of  this method:

[image]

The article included links to the resource definition in its original & modified form:

*Original:*

```
4040 DIALOG 0, 0, 295, 204
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "References"
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
   CONTROL "&Available References:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 7, 73, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5050, LISTBOX, LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_MULTIPLESEL | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 7, 24, 193, 123 
   CONTROL "OK", 1, BUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 6, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Cancel", 2, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 23, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Browse...", 5051, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 45, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Help", 5052, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 238, 84, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Result", 5055, BUTTON, BS_GROUPBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 154, 281, 43 
   CONTROL "Location:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 35, 168, 32, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5053, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 75, 168, 198, 8 
   CONTROL "Language:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 35, 180, 36, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5054, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 77, 180, 196, 8 
   CONTROL "&U", 4528, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 211, 62, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "&D", 4529, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 211, 96, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "Priority", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 206, 82, 24, 8 
}
```

*Modified:*

```
4040 DIALOG 0, 0, 455, 305
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "References"
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
   CONTROL "&Available References:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 7, 7, 73, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5050, LISTBOX, LBS_NOTIFY | LBS_MULTIPLESEL | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 7, 19, 382, 235 
   CONTROL "OK", 1, BUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 18, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Cancel", 2, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 40, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Browse...", 5051, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 61, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "&Help", 5052, BUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 398, 240, 50, 14 
   CONTROL "Result", 5055, BUTTON, BS_GROUPBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 8, 260, 442, 37 
   CONTROL "Location:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 14, 271, 32, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5053, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 52, 271, 390, 8 
   CONTROL "Language:", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 14, 282, 36, 8 
   CONTROL "", 5054, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 52, 282, 390, 8 
   CONTROL "&U", 4528, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, 416, 122, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "&D", 4529, BUTTON, BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 416, 149, 14, 14 
   CONTROL "Priority", -1, STATIC, SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 411, 139, 24, 8 
}
```